# HTTP Compression with Apache besides Deflate and gzip?

Tags: apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-compression

I have a server, and I want to set up HTTP Compression. How can I use another compression type for HTTP Compression on my own server? I want to experiment with lzop, lzma or xz, for example.

I know I can use gzip and deflate with mod_gzip and mod_deflate, but I am wondering if there are options to expand this selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only three algorithms officially supported: `deflate` (zip), `compress` (lzw) and `gzip`. You can compress all you want, but no browser won't be able to read it.

Source: [RFC 2616, section 3.5](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

You can still offer a download of e.g. a `bzip2` file, but I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I mostly interesting in testing for performance gain of using another compression algorithm for HTTP compression.

Comment: If you are interested in comparing the performance of compression algorithms, it might be even better to test the compression algorithms directly through their command line tools or the bindings in the programming language of your choice. This way, you can cut off the HTTP overhead. And the Apache modules don't do anything different than invoking the compression libraries, just like the respective CLI command.